# Multiple Typescript errors and I don't know how to fix them - type is not assignable, incompatibility, etc

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing my first app in React + TypeScript and I can't seem to figure out some things by myself.

I get lots of errors and I don't get why. Here's the message

```
Type '{ ref: MutableRefObject<any>; letter: string; onSelectFunction: { onSelectAnswer: (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>) => void; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Content'.
  Types of property 'onSelectFunction' are incompatible.
    Type '{ onSelectAnswer: (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>'.
      Type '{ onSelectAnswer: (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>) => void; }' provides no match for the signature '(event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>): void'.
```

Here's the code:
Content.tsx

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect, SyntheticEvent } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Box from './Box';
import ButtonCustom from './Button';

function Content() {
    const correctResponse: string = "C";
    const [selectedResponse, setResponse] = useState<string|null>(null);

    const onSubmitAnswer = () => {
        
    };

    const onSelectAnswer = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>) => {
        console.log(event);        
    };

    const box0 = useRef<any>();
    const box1 = useRef<any>();
    const box2 = useRef<any>();
    const box3 = useRef<any>();
    const box4 = useRef<any>();   
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Box {...{letter: 'A', onSelectFunction: {onSelectAnswer}}} ref={box0}/>
            <Row>
            <Col md>
            <Box {...{ letter: 'A', onSelectFunction: {onSelectAnswer}}} ref={box1} />
            </Col>
            <Col md>
            <Box {...{ letter: 'B', onSelectFunction: {onSelectAnswer}}} ref={box2} />
            </Col>
            <Col md>
            <Box {...{ letter: 'C', onSelectFunction: {onSelectAnswer}}} ref={box3} />
            </Col>
            <Col md>
            <Box {...{ letter: 'D', onSelectFunction: {onSelectAnswer}}} ref={box4} />
            </Col>
            </Row>
            <br/>
            { selectedResponse === correctResponse ? <ButtonCustom {...{onSubmitAnswer: onSubmitAnswer, resolvedQuestion: 1}}/> : <ButtonCustom {...{onSubmitAnswer: onSubmitAnswer, resolvedQuestion: 0}}/> }
        </div>
    );
}

export default Content;
```

Box.tsx

```
import React, { ReactEventHandler } from 'react';
import './Box.css';

type Content = {
  onSelectFunction: ReactEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>,
  letter: string
}

const Box = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Content>((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="box" onSelect={props.onSelectFunction}>
      <span className="box-content">
        {props.letter}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
});

export default Box;
```

I literally have no idea what to do to fix them.

I tried changing onSelectFunction's type to

```
React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>
```

but then I get another errors.

As a beginner, I would be really glad if anybody could explain to me why are these errors thrown and how can I fix them.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYCiAbkgHYwASKZAJgDZJTYCuAzksgGascDKMFDCS8khLlyQZsfAJ4UAFkhjA0JcvAC%20cLlAgg4AcigEYhgNwAoUJFi5EEAO7YAwhHpxtu-UZPoYALQARhAQMGwwUChghtbg0PAAQhAAHjp6BoYAdAD0ySkWlpYwsmBIcG4UGnAAvLiWcHAQZHxIjBgAYixkGMDNAFz4-uoU1HSMUAA8lAAqALIAMgAiwMSEjCAaAHyYDXCMMMJQgxFQwGQA5paaRWjNEXD5tUMYWVzQjihQtNzT88urdZITYUVzNYQULYACihYD0YDY2BMXAAlLUtvVGiYYCwoGQ4FC9o1JrRVnBkTUcMjtGh6Cg2GwAHIoTY1ABEIRSbKaLTaUhglLhEARWWarXaMC6PRUzU0WyJjTgkzYYBocFp9KZLKQ7M5ATuVQobPlitNuCFIoORxuZqVORVNBNismOVJxCdKKsmk9RS43V6zQq4I0ULROAVBoedygJgwyBV9yQJ0i5wuzzZLjZVlNkfgAG0OBKkD8kAmyBxsBwYPHIOWkABdZ7sJACIRIZUpy4AHzILHo9Ghvf7Poj93gYpYQRAwBgAEFy44mM9Q%20jMba4ArNFZR%20Xx7yJfO2IuoMukKQKIM5IplKoRjA-osVmsNhpsHetmiahjw%20v1fd3EgWT0BAFxQmeGier%20m7bjmY5wJyAAMTYcL8NCyNCPqwbu8GpAAjMhnBIFwkxoRh2aKrmOEpAATARqFkOhobkY0lGcgAzHRREkQxZE7g8nIACyccRpFMYqCoKtiuL4oSv4kqsTq-sSTw4FaTCDIYs6GNgYp8p0-oymQgw4LpB4LkwmjaBSOCIZoOSKUpkwIE4DlyW4HggLQrnrpMKlZP5eBqccRhaTp%2078lKAZGbgpn8oex6WVZRGUpyuHaPZCpyTk7nebakzuXAnm5WavmpLg-lZIFyhHBpiTaTy4oRQZfTRSZ4UYPFFmWeSyU2ak1HpcVpoujlmU%20QVRVjXlfkBfs1XqUYLj1bF%20nSi1xkrXO5lQIlPVcClqRsYNU0ldl7hDc6E1eSdw0zZVc2HAthhLMt7WSs1AwxW9nU7d11mCcdSnOmdA43cDzmOBdxJBFAGVA40eCFvyxY1omtQ1HU0axtWpa1hwcAAPxKokLCHM0LjsDAPg4BVbV8JO05bUeC0TlOM4-UipbuKQtAAIosKWhmDGldkYoMvmk1TZAUxE1O06zjM-YMCvs9tnNsNzxb84L61wAhln2Z4J0um6Dk%20jclhICktjwLQREoH28CVBCMDmEAA)

Comment: why are you spreading your props when defining your boxes?

Comment: Do you have a way of providing quick access to this as a [mre], like perhaps a link to a properly configured web IDE project that demonstrates this behavior?  Otherwise you're expecting others to either spend a bunch of time trying to set it up themselves, or you want people to answer without actually testing the code.

Comment: @Jerome otherwise I get "Parsing error: ... expected"

Comment: @jcalz I'll do one right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working. Please note that I change the name of the `type Content` to `TContent` to avoid confusion and better readability

```
type TContent = {
  onSelectFunction: ReactEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>,
  letter: string
}

const Box = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, TContent>((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="box" onSelect={props.onSelectFunction}>
      <span className="box-content">
        {props.letter}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
});




function Content() {
    const correctResponse: string = "C";
    const [selectedResponse, setResponse] = useState<string|null>(null);

    const onSubmitAnswer = () => {
        
    };

    const onSelectAnswer = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>) => {
        console.log(event);        
    };

    const box0 = useRef<any>();
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Box letter="A" onSelectFunction= {onSelectAnswer} ref={box0}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Content;
```

Comment: I see. But why wasn't it working before?

Comment: I told you. Your props spreading were incorrect and useless in your case

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use spread props, here was the solution :

```
    const propsB:TContent = {
            letter:"B",
            onSelectFunction:onSelectAnswer
        }
    
        return (
            <div>
                <Box letter="A" onSelectFunction= {onSelectAnswer} ref={box0}/>
                <Box {...propsB} ref={box1}/>

                <Box {...{
                letter: "C",
                onSelectFunction: onSelectAnswer
            }} ref={box0} />

            </div>
        );
```